# How to create custom report for category data in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, reports, custom-reports

I am trying to create a report for categories.

**Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_Module',
__DIR__
);
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Vendor_Module::seoreport" title="Seo Reports" translate="title" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="60" parent="Magento_Reports::report" resource="Vendor_Module::report"/>

    <add id="Vendor_Module::index" title="Category Meta Data" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="10" action="module/index" resource="Vendor_Module::index" parent="Vendor_Module::seoreport"/>       
</menu>
```

Once the menu is clicked, I need to load the report screen with, all the category info like,

> Category Id
>
> Category name
>
> Meta Title
>
> Meta description
>
> Category description and etc

Help me with what are the steps I have to follow to get the grid like order and Best seller report with the export feature of Csv and Excel.

Any suggestions are appreciated!! It will be helpful if anyone update me with working code. Thanks..

Comment: Do you need to create custom report like Bestseller of all category, right ?

Comment: @Hiren, Exactly i am looking same,

Comment: do you need filter ?

Comment: @Hiren, Yes I need one filter with drop down, status, 1.enabled categories 2. All categories, No need of date filters

Comment: @Hiren, did you get it, what i am trying to do here?

Comment: hi @Manjunath, got it, have you try any thing ? update your question if you try anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104695/discussion-between-manjunath-and-hiren).

Comment: @Hiren,
I referred this link, https://github.com/yash7690/magento2-customreport, but ddin't work for me

Comment: @Hiren, can you share your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try and quickly provide a path forward but the question is too broad to offer a working example.  I refer to the core Magento_Cms module of a relatively easy to follow example of a Listing UI Component for cms pages.

I'd start with Admin page that displays Listing UI Component.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html

In the above example, you could replace the content of view/adminhtml/layout/exampleadminnewpage_helloworld_index.xml with something like:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="somename_foryourcomponent_listing" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Define the UI Component referenced in the layout file
view/adminhtml/ui_component/somename_foryourcomponent_listing.xml  Here you configure the listing (grid) with to define data provider, toolbars, mass actions, and columns.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-listing-grid.html

The UI Component needs a Data Provider which is defined in the di.xml and provides the data to the grid.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_data_source.html

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="somename_foryourcomponent_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: hi @lan, I am looking complete solution if possible pls update how to get category collection, mainly I am looking for that code. Please update the code for dataSource with listing ui_component file. Also if you can please update me working code, that helps me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @Manjunath I'm sorry but I do not have an existing example and am not in a position to do this work for you.